# PHP class hierarchy - highest class in the hierarchy

Tags: php, debugging

I am interested to know if PHP has a super class like Java's Object.

The reason I would like to know is that I want to overload it for the purpose of gaining insight to my large PHP project. I aim to overload the class to determine what is being called and develop some knowledge about classes which may be deprecated/aren't used.

Potentially, this may be a question of a tool that you may point me to (as I am sure there would be something like this already). I have searched and couldn't find anything (potentially bad google foo skills) and in the case the tool is found I am happy to alter the question so not as to mislead others who find this.

Many thanks everyone.

Comment: It doesn't. But even if it did, how would you "overload" it? There are tools that can tell you exactly what is being called -- debuggers and profilers.

Answer (score 0):

There is no superclass in php. And there is no overloading since PHP is not type save.
However there are tools detecting dead code in your project, e.g. [phpdcd](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpdcd) developed primarily by Sebastian Bergmann. Although it has some limitations it should find most of your dead code.

You might want to read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778683/dead-code-detection-in-php) on stackoverflow for some more solutions.