# Yii2: Dead code detection

Tags: php, yii2, refactoring

I've got a large Yii2 project. Due to heavy development over a long time there have been many refactorings of code. In order to speed up development, not all functions or classes were removed properly although they are definitively not used any more.

How can I detect classes, methods or functions in Yii2 which are not used anymore?

Unfortunately there are not automated tests with a high degree of code coverage. So I have to execute all features of the applications with a mouseclick. Any ideas how to automate this in order to generate high code coverage without extensively writing tests?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dead code detection in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778683/dead-code-detection-in-php)

Comment: No, because the question is rather old and at least on of the projects mentioned isn't alive any more on Github. So how can dead code be detected in Yii2 in 2017?

Comment: The answer to that question still stands.